# How to fix the button at the bottom on my Linear Layout: Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an `ImagePickerButton`, `EditText` and `Send` Button on my UI as shown below:

[image]

> The problem is with the `Send` Button which doesn't fix to the bottom
>   of my Linear Layout. Can anyone say how to make the position of the
>   button fixed to the **bottom** when I type multi line text.

This is my Layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:maxWidth="@android:dimen/notification_large_icon_height"
    tools:context="com.pc.wecare.MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/messageListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:divider="@color/cardview_dark_background"
        android:stackFromBottom="true"
        android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_message" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/photoPickerButton"
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/messageEditText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sendButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:text="SEND" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use

```
android:baselineAligned="false"
```

In your `LinearLayout`. Let me know if it works for you. That's how I solved a similar issue, but it didn't include an `editText`

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the button inside another linear layout to make that happen.

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sendButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:text="SEND"
        />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add attribute `android:baselineAligned="false"` to your `LinearLayout`.

Update your XML as below:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:baselineAligned="false">

    .................
    .........................

</LinearLayout>
```

**Here is an alternative solution using `RelativeLayout`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:maxWidth="@android:dimen/notification_large_icon_height">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/messageListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:divider="@color/cardview_dark_background"
        android:stackFromBottom="true"
        android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_message" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/photoPickerButton"
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sendButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:text="SEND" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/messageEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/photoPickerButton"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/sendButton"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Hope this will help~